# Sync Mautic bounced email status with SalesForce

Tags: mautic

I have the Mautic and Salesforce integration working fairly well, and now I would like to sync the email bounce status back to Salesforce.  This allows Salesforce users to update email addresses when they are talking to prospects and making notes in Salesforce.  I don't see how to sync the bounce back since there is no "email bounced" field in a Mautic contact.

Using Mautic, I can detect bounced emails as shown below once their email has bounced:
[image: Contact with bounced email status]

However, when I go the Salesforce plugin, there's no field to select for this bounce, something like "Email Bounced":

[image: Salesforce sync dialog]

Maybe I can create a custom field called "Email Bounced", but then how would I populate it?  Ideas?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution below assumes the cron jobs for syncing and segments are set up (that's a small project in itself).  It also assumes email inbox monitoring has been setup.

1. Create a field in SalesForce to store the Invalid Email flag.
   See SalesForce help.  Create a Boolean field called "Email Invalid".
2. Create a field in Mautic to store the Invalid Email flag.
   [image: mautic field definition]
3. Create a segment with contacts having a bounced email.
   From https://www.irelandwebsitedesign.com/images/learning-centre/mautic/mautic_docs_en.pdf:
   a. Go to Segments / New.
   b. Type in the segment name. For example Bounced emails.
   c. Select the Filters tab.
   d. Create new Bounced Email equals Yes filter.
   e. Wait for the app/console mautic:segments:update command to be automatically triggered by a cron job or execute it manually.

[image: mautic segment create]

4. Create a campaign to update the bounce date.
   This campaign will update the "Email Invalid" field when a contact is added to this segment.
   [image: create campaign]
5. Set the fields to sync in the plug-in.
   [image: salesforce sync field setup]